# Exempt local user for SSL connection on MySQL server

Tags: mysql, ssl

I have managed to have turned on SSL connection (require_secure_transport=ON) on   MySQL server 5.7. It works fine for both remote and localhost users. However, I don't want the localhost users connected via SSL connection. However can I exempt the local user from the SSL requirement? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the only way to do this would be to update the global configuration to `require_secure_transport=OFF` and then for every remote user set `REQUIRE SSL` flag. Essentially switching to an opt-in type of setup for SSL.

The issue with this is you'd have to remember to add this flag every time you add a new remote user, and could easily be forgotten. May be safer bet to resolve any issues with connecting over SSL locally instead.

Comment: thanks David. Don't how to flag remote users in that way. In reality, localhost user should be very safe unless someone hacked into the server machine. It is really unnecessary to use SSL for local user. Not sure any other DBs can solve this issue easily?

Comment: For flagging remote users, it is just a matter of setting `REQUIRE SSL` on creation (or altering existing) - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html

I wouldn't say the worry is as much about your local user connection being unencrypted, as it is about the chance accidentally of creating a remote user that doesn't require SSL. Once it is switched to an 'opt-in' per-user setup, instead of a blanket 'always use SSL' configuration.

Comment: thanks David. I think it is the current answer for my question. cheers